# JOptionPane equivalent in python?

Tags: python, graphics

Is there anything similar to JOptionPane in python? As in, does it have inbuilt graphics libraries, if so, could you just show how to you would do something similar in Python?

In Java you can simply do this:

```
import java.swing.*;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, World");
```

Also, javaScript has something similar:

```
alert("Hello, World");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends on what GUI framework you use.

- PyQt:

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 
         'Message',
         "Are you sure to quit?",
         QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, 
         QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
```

- wxPython:

```
wx.MessageBox('Download completed',
       'Info', 
        wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

- [tkInter examples](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) (tkInter is a default GUI library in python)

Comment: Isn't there an inbuilt library in Python?